# how to shorten this jquery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I have a 3 by 3 table like this:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="blank.png" alt="blank" id="one"/></td>
    <td><img src="blank.png" alt="blank" /></td>
    <td><img src="blank.png" alt="blank" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="blank.png" alt="blank" /></td>
    <td><img src="blank.png" alt="blank" /></td>
    <td><img src="blank.png" alt="blank" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="blank.png" alt="blank" /></td>
    <td><img src="blank.png" alt="blank" /></td>
    <td><img src="blank.png" alt="blank" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

in my javascript, I have:

```
$("#one").click(function() {

    var src = $("#one").attr("src");

    if (src == "blank.png") {
        $(this).attr("src", "hello.png");
    }
    else if (src == "hello.png") {
        $(this).attr("src", "hi.png");
    }

    else {
        $(this).attr("src", "blank.png");
    }       
});
```

this switches the first cell of the table between 3 images when a user click on it. I know that if I have all 9 unique IDs for each cell, it will work, but I don't want to have a whole mess of codes in my javascipt. so how do I shorten it?

Comment: Do you want to cycle the same three images on all div's?

Comment: check out attribute selectors: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: are you trying to shorten your js function or not repeat it for each cell?

Comment: Your code currently doesn't cycle back to blank. Some of the examples bellow do. Do you want it to cycle or to end with hi.png?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all elements are going through the same image cycle you can use a class and apply your event to all of them. For instance:

```
<td><img src="blank.png" alt="blank" class="image-cycle"/></td>
```

And bind your javascript to all elements with that class:

```
$('.image-cycle').click( function () {
    // your code
    // the only thing that will have to change is 
    var src = $(this).attr("src");
}
```

Comment: No problem. If it's the answer you're looking for feel free to accept it. In either case, I would recommend editing your question to more specifically convey if you were looking to shorten the function, or make it apply to all your divs.

Answer (score 4):

Use a switch statement

```
$("#one").click(function() {
 switch(this.getAttribute("src")){
  case "blank.png":this.setAttribute("src","hello.png");break;
  case "hello.png":this.setAttribute("src","hi.png");break;
  default:this.setAttribute("src","blank.png");break;
 }
});
```

here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9jMHS/1

Comment: shouldn't be the *last case* `default` ?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im - I will correct it, that should be default.

Answer (score 2):

You could map your sources to an object, like this:

```
$("#one").click(function() {
    var srcs = {
        "blank.png": "hello.png",
        "hello.png": "hi.png",
    }, src = $("#one").attr("src");

    $(this).attr("src", srcs[src] || "blank.png");
});
```

This way you avoid the clunky and unsightly `switch` statement and can easily extend the object to add more `src`s.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how clean it is, but shouldn't something like this work?

```
$("#one").click(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr("src");
    var img = ["blank.png", "hello.png", "hi.png"];
    $(this).attr("src", img[(img.indexOf(src.toLowerCase())+1)%3]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var src = this.getAttribute("src");

this.src = src == "blank.png" ? "hello.png" :
           src == "hello.png" ? "hi.png"    :
                                "blank.png";
```